# Error:symfony 3 Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader:

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony3.x

i downloaded a Symfony project from my friends run both
`Composer update` and `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
commands without errors

but when i open the project on my browser i get this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Animaux/Animaux/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:407 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Animaux/Animaux/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php(90): appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher->match('/app_dev.app/') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Animaux/Animaux/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php(262): Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Animaux/Animaux/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php(104): Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\ in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Animaux/Animaux/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 101`
help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Composer update` - It is a bad idea. For normal development or migrate to production, you need to use the same version of dependencies, with the project must be provided `composer.lock` file (versions of dependencies), and you need to use `composer install` instead of `Composer update`.
2. `...Animaux/var/cache/prod/app...` it meant you didn't clear the cache, for development use `https://your_host.com/app_dev.php` for production - clear the cache `php bin/console cache:clear -e prod`
3. Check for PHP version, it must be the same of development.